# What is the difference between MQTT broker and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am building a  messaging app.I found technology needed are MQTT or RabbitMQ. To me both seems doing the same thing in the same way (in terms of subscribing & publishing to a topic).

So basically what is the main difference between these two and what are the advantage of each on other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really a valid comparison, one is a protocol and the other is an implementation of that protocol

RabbitMQ is a message broker that supports multiple messaging protocols including MQTT, AMQP, STOMP via a plugin architecture